# Expanding an element using CSS and pushing other elements out of the way

Tags: html, css

I want the nav elements within this code snippet to push the others out of the way and take up and bigger area and push the other elements out of the way.

```css
.nav-component{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.705);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid;
    
}

.nav-component:hover{
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: scaleY(2);
    background-color: #e2e2e2c2;
}
```

```html
<nav class='nav-container'>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Projects</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Experience</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforms work on their own layer and don't link with the standard position and repaint tasks of the browser. To expand the box remove the transform properties and use padding instead.

```css
.nav-component{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.705);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid;
    
}

.nav-component:hover{
    background-color: #e2e2e2c2;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class='nav-container'>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Projects</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Experience</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-component">
        <div class="li">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```